# How do I grab (and use) the element being clicked in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So basically what I'm trying to do is apply one click event, and then using event.target determine exactly what was clicked on. After determining what was clicked on, I can then use that to manipulate the DOM. Below is the closest I could get to giving me something somewhat usable, but it doesn't give me 'exactly what I clicked on'.

```
$("body").click(function(event) {

    alert(event.target.nodeName); // Alerts the type of element you clicked on, but doesn't return anything 'usable' to manipulate the DOM

});
```

Comment: What would you like to be returned?

Answer (score 6):

for jQuery, `$(event.target)` will give you a jQuery object containing your clicked element.  Then you can manipulate to your hearts content.

### --UPDATE

I see that your binding the `click()` event to `$('body')`  So when you click the *body* of your document, `click` is fired with `e.target` being the *body*.  You probably want to attach that `click` event listener to a more specific element, see: http://jsfiddle.net/nn4sJ/8/  for an example

Comment: This is correct. In jQuery, event.target always contains the element the user clicked on, but it's the raw element. This is why you wrap it in $() to turn it back to a jQuery object.